# plan was found but it seems to be invalid possibly due to postprocessing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I plan trajectory, the move_group print the message follow

```
[ WARN] [1478232670.643146875]: Fail: ABORTED: Motion plan was found but it seems to be invalid (possibly due to postprocessing). Not executing.
```

I get a solution ,I change the file about `ompl_planning.yaml`. It is like that

```
longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.02 #0.05
```

Get better, but not completely resolved

I want to know what's about this and how to resolve it completely.

thank advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247230/plan-was-found-but-it-seems-to-be-invalid-possibly-due-to-postprocessing/) by [clark_txh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28091/clark_txh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `longest_valid_segment_fraction` determines the density that your selected planner uses to confirm that the found path is collision free. Perhaps the setting if `0.02` is still a bit high in your case, so I would advise you to lower it even further.

Also, from my experience, some planners seem to suffer from these problems than others, so it might be worthwhile to experiment with other planners as well.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0